# A is a $5\times5$ matrix with rank $1$ and trace $2.$ Is it diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is a $5\times5$ matrix with rank $1$ and trace $2.$

I know(or at least think) that its only nonzero eigenvalue is $2.$

However, I do not know how to concretely prove whether or not it is diagonalisable. Instinctively, I look at the algebraic and geometric multiplicities, however, I do not know the geometric multiplicity of my eigenspace(at least, I don't think I know anything about it).

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
The rank-nullity formula shows the kernel has dimension $4$. On the other hand, if the algebraic multiplicity of the $0$ eigenvalue is less than $4$, $A$ would have at least two non-zero eigenvalues (possibly non distinct). Is it compatible with the hypothesis on the rank?

Answer (score 1):

Since the rank of $A$ is $1$, there is some vector $v_1\in F^5\setminus\{0\}$ (where $F$ is the field with which you are working) such that, for each $w\in F^5$, $A.w$ is a multiple of $v_1$. Now, take $v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\in F^5$ such that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\}$ is a basis of $F^5$ and let $P$ be the $5\times5$ matrix whose columns are those five vectors. Then$$P^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\lambda_3&\lambda_4&\lambda_5\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Since $P^{-1}AP$ have the same trace, $\lambda_1=2$. And the matrix $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonalizable:

- $(P^{-1}AP).(1,0,0,0,0)=2.(1,0,0,0,0)$
- $(P^{-1}AP).\left(-\frac{\lambda_5}2,0,0,0,1\right)=0$;
- $(P^{-1}AP).\left(-\frac{\lambda_4}2,0,0,1,0\right)=0$;
- $(P^{-1}AP).\left(-\frac{\lambda_3}2,0,1,0,0\right)=0$;
- $(P^{-1}AP).\left(-\frac{\lambda_2}2,1,0,0,0\right)=0$.

Therefore, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a basis $v_1,\dots,v_4$ for the null-space, which is four-dimensional since
$$
\dim V-\operatorname{rank}T=\dim\operatorname{null}T = 5-1=4.
$$
Extend this to a basis for the entire space by choosing a vector $v_5$ in the orthogonal complement of the null space. Then,
$$
2=\operatorname{Tr}(T)=\sum_{n=1}^5\langle Tv_n,v_n\rangle
=\langle Tv_5,v_5\rangle,
$$
since the other vectors span the null space of $T$. This implies that $Tv_5$ is a non-zero vector.  This vector is also an eigenvector of $T$.
To see this, expand this vector in the basis as
$$
Tv_5=\sum_{n=1}^5\alpha_jv_j,
$$
and act with $T$, yielding
$$
T(Tv_5)=T\left(\sum_{n=1}^5\alpha_nv_n\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^5\alpha_nTv_n=\sum_{n=1}^5\alpha_nTv_n\delta_{n5}
=\alpha_5Tv_5.
$$
We can see from
$$
2=\langle Tv_5,v_5\rangle = \left\langle \sum_{n=1}^5\alpha_nv_n,v_5\right\rangle
=\sum_{n=1}^5\alpha_n\left\langle v_n,v_5\right\rangle
=\alpha_5,
$$
that $\alpha_5\neq0$, and so $T$ has one non-zero eigenvalue.

Thus there are five eigenvectors, $v_1,\dots,v_4,Tv_5$, and so $T$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Rank is 1 hence nullity is n-1. Hence zero eigenvalue has GM n-1. Since trace is two the nth eigenvalue must be two. Hence diagonalisable.